# Java JRuby differences in Multithreading

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I am new to JRuby and Ruby.Is there any difference in multi threading in JRuby and Java.As JRuby is just an implementation of Ruby on JVM where Java also operates on JVM. So are the threads trated in the same way as they are done in Java.

Comment: I don't know, what does the documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

JRuby threads *are* Java threads, so there's really not a huge difference, except for the fact that they're threads intended to run Ruby code within the JRuby runtime in the Java VM.

Ruby's Thread object and associated underpinnings are all mapped completely to Java's internal threading system. This is unlike MRI Ruby where it's using pthreads or the equivalent operating-system version of same.